# Web API Model Shaping For POSTs vs GETS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

A number of models web used that are returned by GETS contain various properties that the user not never write back to. I'm wondering how the Web API /MVC community at large is handling hiding these properties from the user? I understand probably safest way to to create a model that represents each operation and it's payload but i'm wondering if there's anything a little more interesting and flexible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly broad question, but we're currently using models tailored to each operation, and then using [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to map the data to our underlying business model classes.

So we'll have two tailored for gets and posts, and a separate one used in our business layer and map between them.

We use [JSON patch](https://github.com/KevinDockx/JsonPatch) for our patch operations.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Clint. Spent a ton of time with AutoMapper of the past couple of days based on your recommendation. Solid stuff. I've gone as far as to implement such that we can pass around specific version of models.  Curious if you're doing any API versioning.  Using anything specific to assist with Controller/Model versioning?

Comment: @Mike we are! We're using Swashbuckle, which is a nuget package that adds the swagger.io open API standard system to our API. Our versioning is just the same rest paths (for the most part), but with a /v2/ prepend so url.com/api/v2/[usual api path here]. Swagger has some nice API doc discovery and playground stuff built in that makes versioning and the such nice to do!